# Vetor fazer uma consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Olá pessoal estou tentando fazer um consulta usando vetor, mas até onde já aprendi o comando sql não comporta o vetor da forma que estou fazendo então meu resultado é variável vazia.

```
$idcliente=$_SESSION['id_cliente'];
$loja=$_POST['loja'];
$quant[0]=$_POST['quant'];
$quant[1]=$_POST['quant2'];
$quant[2]=$_POST['quant3'];
$produtos[0]=$_POST['produto'];
$produtos[1]=$_POST['produto2'];
$produtos[2]=$_POST['produto3'];
$tipo=$_POST['ttipo'];
$acrescimo=$_POST['acrescimo'];
$pedido=$_POST['pedido'];
$entrega=$_POST['entrega'];
$montagem=$_POST['montagem'];
$tsmg=$_POST['tsmg'];

$x=mysqli_query($conn,"select*from produtos where descricao='$produtos'");
$prt=mysqli_fetch_array($x);


    $idproduto[]=$prt['id_produto'];
    $codigo[]=$prt['codigo'];
    $descricao[]=$prt['descricao']."";
    $cor[]=$prt['cores'];
    $marca[]=$prt['marca'];
    $valorm[]=$prt['valormontagem'];

  print_r($descricao);
```

Aqui é o trecho que envia os dados para os comandos de cima.

```
    <td><input list='produtos' name='produto'/>
    <datalist id='produtos'><?php
    $sql= mysqli_query($conn,"select descricao from produtos order by descricao");
    while ($resp = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

     $group=$resp['descricao'];
    echo "
   <option value='$group','$cor'>";
   }

   ?> </datalist></td>
```

Fiz com 2 produtos como teste.

```
   print_r($produtos);
   Array ( [0] => BERCO CHANTILY [1] => BERCO ALEGRIA [2] => )

   print_r($descricao);
   Array ( [0] => )
```

Comment: Onde está a variável `$produto`? O que é ela?

Comment: Ela vem de um formulário. Nesse campo ele está lendo uma tabela e exibindo para seleção. Dei um `print_r` e nessa parte está exibindo perfeitamente.

Comment: Ou seja `$produto` é um array certo? Coloque por favor o formato do array para lhe poder ajudar

Comment: Sou estudante então me desculpe essa pergunta idiota. Fora o conteúdo que já mostrei não sei como lhe mostra o formato da array, se puder me dar uma dica eu ficaria muito agradecido.

Comment: Pode colocar exatamente a impressão do `print_r($produtos)`

Comment: Feito, esta editado pra facilitar a organização.

Comment: E quer ir buscar por ex: os produtos cujo as descrições são BERCO CHANTILY e BERCO ALEGRIA certo?

Comment: Certo amigo exatamente isso.

Comment: Veja se isto em baixo resulta

Comment: Retirei a resposta, visto que não estava  ajudar, basicamente corrigi `foreach($produtos as $prod) {
    $query .= " descricao='$prod' OR";
}
$query = rtrim($query, ' OR');`, de `AND` para `OR`. Se não conseguir não vejo que mais possa ser

Comment: Sua resposta estava certa @Miguel. Algum detalhe que eu não vi também que não deu certo.

Comment: Exatamente fiz os teste e funcionou perfeitamente obrigado a todos que me ajudaram aprendi algo novo e sou muito grato.

Comment: Pois eu testei aqui e também deu @AndreiCoelho, mas estava a ser tão má aceite que retirei a pensar que estava com um erro crasso

Comment: Relaxe quando corrigiu suas observações funcionou perfeita.

Comment: Não há problema. Entretando DaniloAraujo deveria aceitar a resposta do @AndreiCoelho que funciona bem e é uma solução para o problema

Comment: Na verdade @Miguel sua resposta está mais correta.   Gostaria que quem a negativou que fizesse alguma observaçao.

Comment: Obrigado @AndreiCoelho. Secalhar negativaram no inicio, por lapso fiz uns erros de sintaxe

Comment: Entendi, pode ser. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
...
$query = "select * from produtos where";
foreach($produtos as $prod) {
    $query .= " descricao='$prod' OR";
}
$query = rtrim($query, ' OR');
$x = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($prt = mysqli_fetch_array($x)) {
    $idproduto[]=$prt['id_produto'];
    $codigo[]=$prt['codigo'];
    $descricao[]=$prt['descricao']."";
    $cor[]=$prt['cores'];
    $marca[]=$prt['marca'];
    $valorm[]=$prt['valormontagem'];
}

print_r($descricao);
```

Comment: fiz alguns ajustes, pois notei pequenos erros de digitação, mas mesmo assim esta ocorrendo esse erro dentro do `while` Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in..../ line28

Comment: corrigi. Peço desculpa foi um erro parvo de sintaxe. corrigi na linha `... = mysqli_query(...` e na do `while (...`

Comment: esse é seu codigo com os ajustes:                                                   $query = "select * from produtos where";
foreach($produtos as $prod) {
    $query= " descricao='$prod' AND";
}
$query = rtrim($query, ' AND');
$x = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($prt=mysqli_fetch_array($x)){ 
    $idproduto[]=$prt['id_produto'];
    $codigo[]=$prt['codigo'];
    $descricao[]=$prt['descricao'];
    $cor[]=$prt['cores'];
    $marca[]=$prt['marca'];
    $valorm[]=$prt['valormontagem'];
}

Comment: Infelizmente amigo, percebi os equívocos no código e fiz as correções. Inclusive removi `.=` para `=` mas mesmo assim tenho uma falha relatada dentro do `while`, que por sinal nas varias vezes que tentei fazer o código funcionar tive algumas vezes a mesma condição.

Comment: Mas isso é para continuar assim `.=`. serve para incrementar texto à query inicial

Comment: se eu o deixar ele faz o comando mas não me da o `print_r`. deixando a pagina completamente vazia.

Comment: Não exibe nenhum erro? experimente fazer `echo $query` antes do `while` e `echo $prt['descricao'];` dentro do `while`. O que imprime `echo $query`?

Comment: fiz em diversos lugares e antes do while me retorno o seguinte `echo` select * from produtos where descricao='BERCO 8020' AND descricao='BERCO ALEGRIA'

Comment: E dentro do while nada? Secalhar é porque não há nenhuma linha a ser retornada, essa query está certa. Não há erro aí

Comment: Mas espere aí... Agora estou a pensar numa coisa, como é quer que haja um produto com duas descrições diferentes?? Não é possível vou trocar o `AND` por `OR`. Corrigido

Comment: infelizmente dentro do while não acontece nada. fiz junto ao `while` or msqli_print error(). replicou o mesmo erro infinitamente.

Comment: Já pôs com essa correção? Qual é o erro mesmo? Veja que alterei o código em cima

Answer (score 3):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
 <?php 

// abaixo são enviados 3 produtos

$produtos[0]=$_POST['produto'];
$produtos[1]=$_POST['produto2'];
$produtos[2]=$_POST['produto3'];

// contamos a quantidade

$quantidadeProdutos = count($produtos);

// agora vamos selecionar produto por produto e cada produto faremos a inserção nas arrays

for ($y = 0; $y < $quantidadeProdutos; $y++){

    $produto = $produtos[$y];
    $x=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from produtos where descricao='$produto'");
    while($prt=mysqli_fetch_array($x)){

        $idproduto[]=$prt['id_produto'];
        $codigo[]=$prt['codigo'];
        $descricao[]=$prt['descricao']."";
        $cor[]=$prt['cores'];
        $marca[]=$prt['marca'];
        $valorm[]=$prt['valormontagem'];

    }

}

print_r($descricao);

?>
```

Comment: Se puder dar uma dica para melhorar @Andrei Coelho. Você aí está a fazer uma chamada à base de dados por loop, podia ser reduzida a uma só para todos. Vou restaurar o minha resposta só para você ver uma alternativa

Comment: @Miguel, nao tenho nada a acrescentar. Gostei da sua resposta. Abraço! =)

Comment: Obrigado @Andrei, para ti também